# | androidstudio | how to editing existing document (.doc , .pdf)

Tags: android-studio

Sir, please tell me how to editing existing file documents like .pdf .doc and etc in androidstudio ? 
Searching in google but my problem no solved . Please tell me or give me link for solving my problem

Comment: Android Studio is a code editor (for writing Android apps). It is not a rich document editor. Nor is it designed to edit the assets/resources that are bundled into an Android application (beyond fairly simple operations). Why are you attempting to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: I have a simple project to build app android (apk) . And my project is editing doc file.